# Indexing np.einsum for summation

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to perform the following summation of a vector (v) and two matrices (B) using np.einsum

A[i,j] = (sum from k=1 to N) v[k]*B[k,i]*B[k,j]

`A  = np.einsum('k,ki,kj->ij',v,B,B)`

I expect that this summation over the index k will result in an i x j matrix but am unsure if this is performing the summation or just the multiplication

Comment: So, what's the confusion/question?

Comment: Is this actually performing the summation or simply the multiplication?

Comment: I think it's performing elementwise-multiplication+sum reduction.

Comment: Repeated `k` on the left, and none on the right means it will sum over `k`.  The basic operation of a `einsum` is `sum of products`, but with detailed control over which axes are multiplied together, and which are summed.